# There is a condition where i need to convert Array of objects into Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a condition where i need to convert Array of objects into Array of Arrays.
An array is given below as data convert this array as formatedArray.

```
data = [
      {
        "total": 1,
        "third": 0,
        "city": "Agra",
        "first": 0,
        "second": 0
      },
      {
        "total": 2,
        "third": 0,
        "city": "Agra",
        "first": 0,
        "second": 0
      },
      {
        "total": 3,
        "third": 0,
        "city": "Delhi",
        "first": 0,
        "second": 0
      },
      {
        "total": 4,
        "third": 0,
        "city": "Delhi",
        "first": 0,
        "second": 0
      }
]
```

How can I convert the array of objects above into an array of arrays below?

```
formatedArray=[
  "Agra":[
    {
      "total": 1,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Agra",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    },
    {
      "total": 2,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Agra",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    }
  ],
  "Delhi":[
    {
      "total": 4,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Delhi",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    },
    {
      "total": 4,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Delhi",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: just aggregate elems of your array by city: take a map, check if map has the city, if yes use the value to push the element, otherwise adds an empty city to the map and push it your elem

Comment: This is not an Array, it looks like a Json (Java). You don't state the language

Comment: What language are you using?   ( Edit your post and include the corresponding tag next to `arrays`. )

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through vanilla JavaScript. The method which can be used is `reduce()` method:

```
const data = [
    {
      "total": 1,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Agra",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    },
    {
      "total": 2,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Agra",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    },
    {
      "total": 3,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Delhi",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    },
    {
      "total": 4,
      "third": 0,
      "city": "Delhi",
      "first": 0,
      "second": 0
    }
];
```

and the code looks like this:

```
const desired = data.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
    acc[currentValue.city] = acc[currentValue.city] || [];        
    acc[currentValue.city].push(currentValue);    
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(desired);
```

Comment: You don't need the if: (acc[currentValue.city] exists from previous line) @StepUp

Comment: @user753642 you are right! It is great catch! Thanks for so great comment! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggesty you taking a look at the lodash groupby function:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

```
formatedArray = _.groupBy(data, obj => obj.city);
```

Here is a quick stackblitz-example based on angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpj8jh

Comment: perfect! Glad it solved your problem. Would you mind accepting my answer as correct? Greetings